# web services how to get the wsdl from the url web service

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl

I have the web service url

http://seguriteca.sir.renfe.es/u35/GDN/Seguriteca2017/Normativa.nsf/DegradadoMercancias

and I want to get the wsdl to obtain the java classes from java.

How can I get the wsdl?

Edited.

I attach my wsdl. I want to know which are the java classes generated from this wsdl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions targetNamespace="urn:DefaultNameSpace"
    xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
    xmlns:apachesoap="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap"
    xmlns:impl="urn:DefaultNameSpace" xmlns:intf="urn:DefaultNameSpace"
    xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
    xmlns:wsdlsoap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <wsdl:types>
        <schema targetNamespace="urn:DefaultNameSpace"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
            <element name="LINEAS" type="xsd:string" />
            <element name="TRAMOS" type="xsd:string" />
            <element name="CODUSUARIO" type="xsd:string" />
            <element name="NOMUSUARIO" type="xsd:string" />
            <complexType name="LISTADO">
                <sequence>
                    <element name="RESULTADO" type="xsd:string" />
                    <element name="MSG" type="xsd:string" />
                </sequence>
            </complexType>
            <element name="LISTADODOCUMENTOSReturn" type="impl:LISTADO" />
        </schema>
    </wsdl:types>
    <message name="LISTADODOCUMENTOSRequest">
        <part element="impl:LINEAS" name="LINEAS" />
        <part element="impl:TRAMOS" name="TRAMOS" />
        <part element="impl:CODUSUARIO" name="CODUSUARIO" />
        <part element="impl:NOMUSUARIO" name="NOMUSUARIO" />
    </message>
    <message name="LISTADODOCUMENTOSResponse">
        <part element="impl:LISTADODOCUMENTOSReturn"
            name="LISTADODOCUMENTOSReturn" />
    </message>
    <portType name="DegradadoMercanciasNotes">
        <operation name="LISTADODOCUMENTOS">
            <input message="impl:LISTADODOCUMENTOSRequest"
                name="LISTADODOCUMENTOSRequest" />
            <output message="impl:LISTADODOCUMENTOSResponse"
                name="LISTADODOCUMENTOSResponse" />
        </operation>
    </portType>
    <binding name="DominoSoapBinding"
        type="impl:DegradadoMercanciasNotes">
        <wsdlsoap:binding style="document"
            transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
        <operation name="LISTADODOCUMENTOS">
            <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction="" />
            <input name="LISTADODOCUMENTOSRequest">
                <wsdlsoap:body use="literal" />
            </input>
            <output name="LISTADODOCUMENTOSResponse">
                <wsdlsoap:body use="literal" />
            </output>
        </operation>
    </binding>
    <service name="DegradadoMercanciasNotesService">
        <port binding="impl:DominoSoapBinding" name="Domino">
            <wsdlsoap:address
                location="http://seguriteca.sir.renfe.es:80/u35/GDN/Seguriteca2017/Normativa.nsf/DegradadoMercancias?OpenWebService" />
        </port>
    </service>
</definitions>
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the framework been used for Web Service implementation.
Usually you can find it appending "?wsdl" or ".wsdl" to the web service URL.
So, I would try with http://seguriteca.sir.renfe.es/u35/GDN/Seguriteca2017/Normativa.nsf/DegradadoMercancias?wsdl or http://seguriteca.sir.renfe.es/u35/GDN/Seguriteca2017/Normativa.nsf/DegradadoMercancias.wsdl

Comment: I edited my question. I get the wsdl and now I want to generate the java classes. I attach the wsdl. What classes are generated from wsdl?

Comment: All the classes needed to bind requests and responses

Comment: Then, I have to get LISTADODOCUMENTOSRequest , LISTADODOCUMENTOSReturn, LISTADODOCUMENTOSResponse classes

Comment: and even LISTADO, that is a complex type defined in schema section